# ticket availability Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to count how many ticket sold and how many available using javascript and html.
I need a user to be able to select a number of tickets they need. Base on user's selections the system should be able to let the user know if ticket has run out . If ticket available the system can than alert a thank you message. Simple as it sound but I just can't get my head around it.

Anyone out there willing to help. I appreciate a lot.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<script language="javascript">

  var ticket = ["q_available": 20,"q_sold": 0 ];

  if (q_sold >= q_available){

       alert("ticket sold out. Sorry");

       }else
            {
                 alert("Thank you.");
        }

      </script>

       <select name="ticketing" id="ticketing">
            <option value="1">1<option>
            <option value="2">2<option>
            <option value="3">3<option>
            <option value="4">4<option>
            <option value="5">5<option>
       </select>
```

Comment: You've not said what your problem is.  This will likely be closed in its current format.  You probably want to start by looking at the difference between `[ ]` and `{ }` though.

Comment: @ Darren Young sorry, I meant I need to be able to count how many tickets has sold out (depending to the user selection from the drop down list) and so long as is within 20 tickets. Users can continue selecting their tickets. Thanks

Comment: So you want a function that runs when the user selects a number of tickets, and processes that selection?  You should probably add that information into your question, so that someone doesn't close it out for lack of info.

Comment: @freginold, thanks for point that out. Let me add that in.

Comment: @Leni_14 No problem.  See my answer below for a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution.  You had several typos (`<option>` as a closing tag instead of `</option>`, for example) but your code was a good start.

I added functionality to check the current number of tickets, compare to the number requested, and buy them if they are available.  The code also resets the `<select>` value back to a non-selectable default so that it will run the function when the user picks a number.

```js
var q_available = 20;
var q_sold = 0;

function buyTicket(num) {
  var soldOut = false;
  if (q_sold >= q_available) {
    alert("Tickets sold out. Sorry.");
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    // loop through # of tickets to see if sold out
    q_sold++;
    if (q_sold >= q_available) {
      if (i < num) {
        alert("You can only buy " + i + " tickets... Sorry.");
        soldOut = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (!soldOut) {
    alert("Thank you. We have " + (q_available - q_sold) + " tickets left.");
    document.getElementById('ticketing').value = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="ticketing" id="ticketing" onchange="buyTicket(this.value);">
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Please select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for.  Just realised how far I was. Thank you very much

Comment: @Leni_14 No problem.  The code is pretty self-explanatory, but if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Ok thanks. I tried to add these code to my webpage but the alert message not displayed. I added the select option inside the div and then create js file outside and then add/link the js extension file at the bottom of the webpage. I meant like this <script src="js/tickets.js"></script>  before the </body> tag

Comment: @Leni_14 Did you keep the code the same?  (same IDs, same function names, etc.)

Comment: yes I have. All same nothing added. Not sure if it has to do with the chrome but I will find out. thanks

Comment: @Leni_14 Does the dev tools console show any error messages?

Comment: the console message says UncaughReferenceError: buyTicket  is not defined at HTMLselectElement.Onchange

Comment: It sounds like the HTML file and JS file aren't linked up correctly. Put an alert -- `alert("test");` -- as the first line in the JavaScript file where you have the `buyTicket` function -- does the alert show up when you load the page?

Comment: Okay, that means the HTML file isn't loading your JS file.  Make sure the path, `<script>` tag, and file name are all correct.

Comment: Yes you're right. As soon as I put those code in separate webpage they work fine. Sorry for troubling you. Thanks again for your help.